# Button changes title every time pressed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton, title, uicontrol

Im trying this, but when i press it it dont changes, it only displays text.
Also tried if else functions, but with no results.

.h

```
IBOutlet UIButton *poga1;
@property (nonatomic, retain)  UIButton *poga1;
```

.m

```
@synthesize poga1;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[poga1 setTitle:@"My Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[poga1 setTitle:@"My Selected Title" forState:UIControlStateSelected];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: If you added a title through the storyboard (the gui interface) then delete it.

.h
//create an IBOutlet action. How? You right-click the button and drag it to the .h file. A pop up happens and you need to click the drop down and switch it to action
//should be something like

```
- (IBAction)yourButton:(id)sender;

.m
//there will be a new function in your .m which is your button action function. 
@synthesize poga1;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[poga1 setTitle:@"My Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[poga1 setTitle:@"My Selected Title" forState:UIControlStateSelected];

}

- (IBAction)Start:(id)sender
{
```

/* if you want this to change the text each time it's pressed then, you need a global counter that your increment each time the button is pressed. then you will have a if statement saying if the counter is equal to 1 (pressed once) then set title to hello, if the counter is equal to 7 (pressed 7 times) set title to goodbye. */

```
 [sender setTitle:@"whatever" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the action of the button and change the title, cause UIButton doenst have a permanent state as selected, like a switch or a toggle.

If you want to change the title when the user press:

```
-(IBAction) onClick: (id) sender {
  [(UIButton *) sender setHighlighted:YES];
}
```

Comment: But then text will displayed only while user keeps button pressed. Im trying to text change on every touch and stays until button is again pressed.

Comment: So then the only option is to capture the action and change the title when the user selects the button, cause the button cannot be "selected", its not a switch

Comment: Sounds logic.. But I have no idea how to make that action, could you help please?