# UIButton disappearing after button click

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I click on a button in one row, the button in a different row disappears. Why might this be happening?

I looked at the following question and all the other questions within it, but nothing really answers my issue.

- [Custom, Imageless UIButton title disappears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130515/custom-imageless-uibutton-title-disappears)

I used the Debug `Color Blended Layers` to see if it's just a color thing, but my button just appears to disappear completely. I suspected this was a `button.hidden` property thing so I hardcoded `button.hidden = NO;` but nothing has changed.

What went wrong here?

Table Control Code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([locationObjectsArray count] > 0)
    {
        return [locationObjectsArray count]+1;
    }
    else
        return 1;
}

// Populate the Table View with member names
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier= @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    // Configure the Cell...
    UIButton *selectButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    UILabel *cityNamesText = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    UIButton *editButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:3];

    //NSLog(@"[locationObjectsArray count]: %lu", (unsigned long)[locationObjectsArray count]);

    if (indexPath.row >= [locationObjectsArray count]) {
        // locationObjectsArray count == 0; Empty Array
        cityNamesText.text = @"Add New Location";

        NSLog(@"%ld: %@", (long)indexPath.row, @"Add New Location");
        editButton.hidden = NO;
        [editButton setTitle:@"Add" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        //[editButton setTitle:@"Add" forState:UIControlStateApplication];
        selectButton.hidden = YES;
    }
    else if ([locationObjectsArray count] > 0) {
        LocationObject *locObject = [locationObjectsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"%ld: %@", (long)indexPath.row, [locObject getLocationName]);
        cityNamesText.text = [locObject getLocationName];
        selectButton.hidden = NO;
        editButton.hidden = NO;
    }

    // Assign button tags
    selectButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    editButton.tag = indexPath.row;

    [selectButton addTarget:self action:@selector(selectButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [editButton addTarget:self action:@selector(editButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    LocationObject *selectedLocationObject = [self loadLocationObjectWithKey:@"locObject"];
    // Set Selected Cell to different Color
    if ([cityNamesText.text isEqualToString:[selectedLocationObject getCityName]]) {
        // Change to lightBlue color
        UIColor * lightBlue = [UIColor colorWithRed:242/255.0f green:255/255.0f blue:254/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:lightBlue];
    }
    else
    {
        // All non-selected cells are white
        //[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        //editButton.hidden = NO;
    }

    return cell;
}

// Select Button Clicked method
-(void)selectButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
    if ([locationObjectsArray count] == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"locObject count == 0");
        // locationObjectsArray count == 0; Empty Array
        // City name input is invalid
        UIAlertView * alert =[[UIAlertView alloc ] initWithTitle:@"No Locations Set"
                                                         message:@"Please add a new location."
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"locObject count > 0");
        if (sender.tag >= locationObjectsArray.count) {
            // Create local isntance of the selected locationObject
            LocationObject *locObject = [locationObjectsArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
            // Set locObject as current default locObject
            [self saveLocationObject:locObject key:@"locObject"];
        }


        [mainTableView reloadData];
    }
}

// Edit Button Clicked method
-(void)editButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
    if ([locationObjectsArray count] == 0) {
        // locationObjectsArray count == 0; Empty Array
        UIAlertView * alert =[[UIAlertView alloc ] initWithTitle:@"Add Location"
                                                         message:@"Input City Name"
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                               otherButtonTitles: nil];
        alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
        [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Save"];
        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
        selectedObjectInArray = sender.tag;
        UIAlertView * alert =[[UIAlertView alloc ] initWithTitle:@"Edit Location"
                                                         message:@"Input City Name"
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                               otherButtonTitles: nil];
        alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
        [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Save"];
        [alert show];
    }
}

// Handle alertView
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if ([alertView.title isEqualToString:@"Add Location"]) {
        // Add Location Alert View
        if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"You have clicked Cancel");
        }
        else if(buttonIndex == 1)
        {
            NSLog(@"You have clicked Save");
            UITextField *cityNameTextField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
            NSString *saveLocationName = cityNameTextField.text;
            NSLog(@"saveLocationName: %@", saveLocationName);
            if ([self isLocationValid:saveLocationName] == YES) {
                NSLog(@"location is valid. locationObjectsArray.count = %lu", locationObjectsArray.count);
                if (locationObjectsArray.count == 0) {
                    locationObjectsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
                }
                // City name input is valid
                LocationObject *locObject = [[LocationObject alloc] init];
                [locObject setCityName:saveLocationName];
                locObject.byCityName = YES;
                [locationObjectsArray addObject:locObject];

                NSLog(@"After addObject: locationObjectsArray.count = %lu", locationObjectsArray.count);

                [self saveLocationArrayObject:locationObjectsArray key:@"locationObjectsArray"];
                [mainTableView reloadData];
            }
            else
            {
                // City name input is invalid
                UIAlertView * alert =[[UIAlertView alloc ] initWithTitle:@"City Name Invalid"
                                                                 message:@"Unable to locate input city."
                                                                delegate:self
                                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                       otherButtonTitles: nil];
                [alert show];
            }
        }
    }
    else if ([alertView.title isEqualToString:@"Edit Location"])
    {
        // Edit Location Alert View
        if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"You have clicked Cancel");
        }
        else if(buttonIndex == 1)
        {
            NSLog(@"You have clicked Save");
            UITextField *cityNameTextField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
            NSString *saveLocationName = cityNameTextField.text;
            if ([self isLocationValid:saveLocationName]) {
                // City name input is valid
                int selectedIndex = (int)selectedObjectInArray;
                LocationObject *locObject = [locationObjectsArray objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];
                [locObject setCityName:saveLocationName];
                [locObject setByCityName:(Boolean *)TRUE];
                [locationObjectsArray setObject:locObject atIndexedSubscript:selectedIndex];
                [self saveLocationArrayObject:locationObjectsArray key:@"locationObjectsArray"];
                [mainTableView reloadData];
            }
            else
            {
                // City name input is invalid
                UIAlertView * alert =[[UIAlertView alloc ] initWithTitle:@"City Name Invalid"
                                                                 message:@"Unable to locate input city."
                                                                delegate:self
                                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                       otherButtonTitles: nil];
                [alert show];
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Before:

[image: Edit button is visible]

After check button is selected:

[image: Edit button is gone]

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: OK updated with the tableView code @godmoney

Comment: You might be having a problem with the way you're using tags. You get reference to the buttons by finding the views with tags 1, 2, and 3, but later you set the tags of two of those buttons based on the indexPath.row. Usually, you would do one or the other of these, but not both. Personally, I really don't like finding views based on their tags. I always make a custom cell class, and give my views IBOutlets. It's cleaner, and makes your code more readable.

Comment: Use a custom subclass already, `viewWithTag:` is useful only for simple views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is in these lines in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
// Assign button tags
selectButton.tag = indexPath.row;
editButton.tag = indexPath.row;
```

The tags will get mixed up as the cells are reused, I would recommend trying to omit using tags in this situation and use e.g. IBOutlets as @rdelmar pointed out.